# AfxMessageBox Caption "ERROR"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a project migrated from VS6.0 to VS2010.

In VS6.0, the caption of all AfxMessageBox is "Schedule Maintenance" which is the value of AFX_IDS_APP_TITLE in rc file. But in VS2010, the caption is "ERROR".

Answer (score 0):

Open .rc file and edit AFX_IDS_APP_TITLE to "Schedule Maintenance" and rebuild it.I hope these will solve your problem.

Comment: Actually, I already checked the rc file and it is already there.

Comment: check  AFX_IDS_APP_TITLE is redefined with "ERROR" .if yes remove it .

Comment: have you use AfxMessageBox only for all message or you have use Messagebox for some of them

Comment: I only use AfxMessageBox.

Comment: You mean in .rc file   AFX_IDS_APP_TITLE       "Schedule Maintenance" is present